# HTML javascript submit form with radio

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, radio-group

So I have a quiz-like form. It contains questions and answers. I need the form to have no radio checked on document ready. I achieved that with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false)
});
```

(as of the comment)
Now I need the form to be submittable only if the user picks ONE answer FOR EACH question.
If a question remains with NO answer checked, there should be an alert box and the form should not be submitted.

The form looks like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVLhD/2/)
of course, it is generated server side by PHP, but this is a sample of what it looks like after generation.
Also, the java function I tried only checks for ONE radio of all radios of all questions. I need to check EACH question for checked radios

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Title says checkboxes. They are different things.

Comment: There is no such thing as .radio()

Comment: Diodeus: <input type="radio" ... What do you call these?

Comment: @user1137313 `radio` is a type for an `input`, jQuery has functions to control DOM elements but there's no function called `radio` except if you are using a plugin. The correct way to uncheck all radio is `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false)`

Comment: Ok. Let's assume that this is not an issue, since, because I generate in PHP the form and the radiobuttons, I can simply chose not to set any of the radios to checked. My problem is that I need a function to check if all the questions in the form have an answer checked. The number of questions is variable, also the number of answers to a question may vary. But a sample of what it looks like can be seen in the fiddle give in the question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modification to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eVLhD/3/.

In the HTML code, I've wrapped each question inside a div: `<div class="question">  </div>`

Then in the submit function, I do: for each question, check if there is a checked option. If there is none, stop the submit, alert and stop the loop.

```
function atleast_onecheckbox(e) {
    var error = 0, i = 1;
    $('div.question').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(':checked').length === 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('no way you submit it without checking a box in question ' + i);
            error++;
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    });
    return error === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the radio's are part of the same collection (per question) then it shouldn't be possible for the user to select more than one. Another thing, are the questions fixed or are they dynamic? I mean, do you always have the same number of questions, or can this amount vary?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment. The questions number is variable, also the answers may vary from question to question. Please check the example in jsfiddle in my question body. Keep in mind that sometimes the form contains 3 questions, other times it contains 7... and so on. It's a dynamic form